# Jquery - delay search until input is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delay the trigger of my search until the user is done typing. I'm using a function built with mark.js (https://markjs.io). It searches as the user types and jumps to the first result as it searches. The problem is that it searches for every letter combination as you type. I.E: searching "help" Searches for "h", "he", "hel", "help". Given the size of the document this is ridiculously slow. Is there something I can do with this function to make it wait until the user is done typing?

Here is the search function I'm using:

```
    $(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".container"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 150,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          accuracy: "exactly",
          separateWordSearch: false,
          done: function() {
//Filter Results//$context.not(":has(mark)").hide();
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is some of the HTML:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="text-input" style="height: 28px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: 1px; margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <br/>
      <button data-search="next">Next</button>
      <button data-search="prev">Previous</button>
      <button data-search="clear">✖</button><br/>
<div class="container">
   <div>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus elementum non arcu id tristique. Cras fringilla nisi erat, non ultricies leo varius eu. Duis venenatis enim sed tristique gravida. Nulla dolor augue, tempor non nisl eget, consequat consequat magna. Nulla quis elit nisl. Integer at tortor molestie, dignissim odio id, pharetra nunc. Maecenas scelerisque porta erat bibendum aliquet. Proin est felis, pretium sit amet consequat eu, aliquet ac erat. Donec tempus, libero sit amet rutrum posuere, leo ipsum gravida odio, quis sodales magna nisl ut lectus.
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can 'setInterval' or start the search only after the length of the string is longer than 3 characters (for example).

Comment: What version of mark.js are you using? There's a recent release that brings performance optimizations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throttle the iniitialization of the search function using a timer and also check if a minimum number of characters exist

Something like:

```
var searchTimer = null,
  minLength = 3,
  searchDelay = 300;

$input.on("input", function() {
  // clear previous timer
  clearTimeout(searchTimer);

  var searchVal = this.value;

  // don't do anything if not enough characters
  if (searchVal.length < minLength) {
    return;
  }  

  // start new timer
  searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          accuracy: "exactly",
          separateWordSearch: false,
          done: function() {
            //Filter Results//$context.not(":has(mark)").hide();
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }, searchDelay);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have done the trick. I might need to do some tweaking to get it slowed down where I want it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can call search function by words like after pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and than call search function.

For Example:

```
$input.on("input", function(e) {

    if (e.which == 13) {
        var searchVal = this.value;
        $content.unmark({
            done: function() {
                $content.mark(searchVal, {
                    accuracy: "exactly",
                    separateWordSearch: false,
                    done: function() {
                        $results = $content.find("mark");
                        currentIndex = 0;
                        jumpTo();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a delayed timer. Basically, when the user presses a key, start the timer instead of calling the search function directly. If the user presses a key again, start the timer over. If the timer ends, do the search.

```
var searchHandler;
var searchDelay = 300;
$('input[type="search"]').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (searchHandler)
    clearTimeout(searchHandler);
})
$('input[type="search"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $('#status').html('Waiting...');
  searchHandler = setTimeout(doSearch, searchDelay)
})

doSearch = function() {
  $('#status').html('Doing the search!');
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/13uxa86p/2/

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a small function for you:

```js
  function simpleDelayTimer() {
  var delay = 2000;
  var timer = null;
  return {
    start:
    function () {
      this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
        alert('Put Code here');
      }, delay);
      return timer;
    },
    reset: function () {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
  }
}
  
  var timer = simpleDelayTimer();
  
  
  function startTimer(){
    if (document.getElementById('timertest').value.trim() == "")
        return;
    
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="timertest">Type here </label> 
<input type="text" id="timertest" placeholder="2000ms timer" onkeyup="startTimer()" />
```

You can put a functin or code in the function body of "setTimeout"